# Finding Horizontal Line In Bitmap Image in C

Tags: c, bitmap, horizontal-line

I am stuck with my assesment. I am given a bitmap with its dimensions (rows and cols) such as this:

```
4 5
0 0 1 1 1
0 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

The task is to find horizontal and vertical longest line and a square (all made of 1). I just need the first kick with the horizontal line.

I have put the bitmap in 1D array and I don't know the next step.

The output of the picture above are the coordinates of the longest horizontal line:

```
3 0 3 4
```

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: That is very easy, did you try anything?

Comment: Why did you put it in an 1D array?

Comment: @Mihai Maruseac - I don't know about OP, but personally, I always found multi-dimensional arrays in C confusing and error-prone. Probably if I used them a lot that would have gone away, but I never had that much use. So I always preferred to use a 1D array and convert multi-dimensional co-ordinates to 1D myself. This can also be more flexible when in-memory layout is important. For example there's no standard C feature for Hilbert-curve based layout, which gives good locality over multiple dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extract the header into structure and data into an array like a[].

Let R and C be number of rows and columns of image. For a given array a[], each row of image starts at a[C*i] where i is the row number. So you can index the row with i, and access each bit in that row with C*i+j, were j less than C. Next you need to do `processing` for each row to find the length of longest horizontal line. Small change to this can be used to index column j and find longest vertical line.

To do the processing I said above, create a structure of point as

```
struct point 
{
  int x;
  int y;

}p1, p2;
```

Also create a variable called `lenh` which will contain length of the horizontal line found. Also user variable `llenh` to store the longest length. For each vertex in row (i, j) indexed by (5i+j). Set `llenh` to 0. Starting in row, on seeing 1 update `lenh`, and see if it is greater than `llenh`. If yes update `p1` point. On seeing 0 update `p2` point and set `lenh` to 0 and also update `llenh`.

I haven't revised this completely. If any errors please comment..

Comment: Thanks! This was the kick I needed :)